# How to get input from InputText() without a button press in PySimpleGui

Tags: python, pysimplegui

Is there a way to be able to get the input from an `InputText()` without having to rely on a button press? I am trying to make a form where the submit button is only available when the input text is not empty, however the only way to get the input from `InputText()` that I have found is with a button which needs to be clicked in order for me to receive the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decide what event by yourself to send the content of the Input element.

- click a button - Add one button into your layout.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [[sg.Input(key='-IN-'), sg.Button('Submit')]]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout)
event, values = window.read()
if event == 'Submit':
    print(values['-IN-'])
window.close()
```

- Button element with Enter key - Wth option `bind_return_key=True`

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [[sg.Input(key='-IN-'), sg.Button('Submit', bind_return_key=True)]]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout)
event, values = window.read()
if event == 'Submit':
    print(values['-IN-'])
window.close()
```

- Input element with Enter key - Binding event `'<Return>'` to your Input element.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [[sg.Input(key='-IN-')]]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True)
window['-IN-'].bind('<Return>', ' ENTER')
event, values = window.read()
if event == '-IN- ENTER':
    print(values['-IN-'])
window.close()
```

- click any keyboard - With option `enable_events=True`

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [[sg.Input(enable_events=True, key='-IN-')]]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout)
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == '-IN-':
        print(values['-IN-'])
window.close()
```

Comment: I used `enable_events=True` on `InputText()` and it worked for me, thanks!